# Rstudio web pages render correctly locally, but not from server

Tags: r, apache, rstudio, r-markdown

- Dev Environment: R 3.3.2 / R Studio 0.99.1266 / Windows 7
- Web server:  Kubuntu ; Apache/2.14.18
- Browser: Firefox 52.0.1

**Context** :
I have a simple set of web pages I'm creating in R Studio for a short course series.  I develop this on a Windows machine, then copy the _site folder to the server. It is the first time I've done web pages in R Studio, but also my server was recently replaced.

Consequently, I don't know if this is an RStudio issue or something to my Apache configuration.  And I don't know how to diagnose where the problem described below lies.

**Problem**

- It looks fine on my Windows machine with Firefox as a `file://` URL
- also looks fine when I open the site on the server,
  but as a `file://` URL (I have a samba share to the server that lets me see this as another drive.)
- similarly, looks OK if I open the site using the command line tool, `xdg-open index.html` on the server machine
- **BUT**, when I open this in Firefox with the server `http://` URL on either the Windows machine or on the server machine, none of the style or other attributes are rendered correctly.

To illustrate:  this is what I see opening the site from my Windows machine, with a `file://` URL

[image]

The server URL is [Introduction to R Graphics](http://datavis.ca/courses/RGraphics/)
which looks like this:

[image]
The _site.yml file is straight-forward:

```
name: "RGraphics"
exclude: ["notes/", "sources/", "*.pptx", "*.bak"]
navbar:
  title: "An Introduction to R Graphics"
  type: inverse
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      icon: fa-home fa-2x   # handy way to use FontAwesome icons in nav!
      href: index.html
    - text: "Abstract"
      icon: fa-file  fa-2x
      href: abstract.html
    - text: "Resources"
      icon: fa-book  fa-2x
      href: resources.html
```

And so are the various .Rmd files, e.g., index.Rmd:

```
---
title: "An Introduction to R Graphics"
author: "Michael Friendly, SCS Short Course"
date: "March, 2017"
---

## Session 1: Overview

- Lecture notes: [1up PDF](R-Graphics1.pdf); [4up PDF](R-Graphics1-2x2.pdf)

#### Topics:

  + Getting started: R, R Studio
  + The roles of graphics in data analysis (exploration, analysis, presentation)
  + What can I do with R graphics: Anything! 
...
```

Comment: When you open it in firefox, can you check all the network traffic in the developer tools to see if any requests for resources are erroring out?

Comment: Yes, I see 403 (forbidden) errors generated by the lines like `<script src="site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` that load JS scripts and CSS.  So this may be a server configuration error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The *diagnosis* of the source of the problem came from the 403 (forbidden) errors noted above.  But the *cause* of the problem was that  folder permissions for `site_libs/` weren’t set correctly. That folder, and all the subfolders containing the javascript libraries needed to be set to `755 (drwxr-xr-x)`, i.e., allowing read and execute permissions to folders for all users.

**Why this happened**: the properties of the `site_libs/` files generated by R Studio on Windows don't map well to the Unix permissions required for the web server.

**Cure**:  On the server, `cd` to the top level of this web tree. Then, use something like

```
 find . -type d -exec chmod 755  {} \;
```